# Convert Column multiple rows to single row output sql

Tags: informix

I have an example query below that I am running that is only on one column, but multiple rows can be displayed:

```
SELECT 
dbspace
FROM tab_info_script
WHERE database = 'dwh_vodac'
AND tabname = 'ft_import_lock'
```

Example output:

```
dbspace2
dbspace4
idxdbs2
dbspace3
idxdbs3
dbspace1
dbspace5
```

My goal is try and convert the multiple rows into a single row output such as below:

```
dbspace2 dbspace4 idxdbs2 dbspace3 idxdbs3 dbspace1 dbspace5
```

This is an informix database I am working with, but many examples I see online are for MySQL or SQLServer, which is very different. So basically I am only working with one column that can generate multiple rows, but instead of multiple rows I want the output to be one row. Is that possible?

Comment: Since your question is about Informix rather than Microsoft SQL Server, I removed the `sql-server` tag and added `Informix` for better visibility.

Comment: https://database.guide/how-to-get-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-separated-list-in-sql/ this would be helpful, but not supported for informix

Comment: A cursory search returned [LISTAGG](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-listagg). Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I have found with the creation of a function and AGGREGATE below I can get the result I want:

Link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715350/show-a-one-to-many-relationship-as-2-columns-1-unique-row-id-comma-separate/716655#716655

```
CREATE FUNCTION gc_init(dummy VARCHAR(255)) RETURNING LVARCHAR;
    RETURN '';
END FUNCTION;

CREATE FUNCTION gc_iter(result LVARCHAR, value VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNING LVARCHAR;
    IF result = '' THEN
        RETURN TRIM(value);
    ELSE
        RETURN result || ' ' || TRIM(value);
    END IF;
END FUNCTION;

CREATE FUNCTION gc_comb(partial1 LVARCHAR, partial2 LVARCHAR)
    RETURNING LVARCHAR;
    IF partial1 IS NULL OR partial1 = '' THEN
        RETURN partial2;
    ELIF partial2 IS NULL OR partial2 = '' THEN
        RETURN partial1;
    ELSE
        RETURN partial1 || ' ' || partial2;
    END IF;
END FUNCTION;

CREATE FUNCTION gc_fini(final LVARCHAR) RETURNING LVARCHAR;
    RETURN final;
END FUNCTION;

CREATE AGGREGATE group_concat
    WITH (INIT = gc_init, ITER = gc_iter,
          COMBINE = gc_comb, FINAL = gc_fini);
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(dbspace)
FROM tab_info_script
WHERE database = 'dwh_vodac'
AND tabname = 'ft_import_lock'
```

Output:

```
dbspace2 dbspace4 idxdbs2 dbspace3 idxdbs3 dbspace1 dbspace5
```

Comment: Jonathan Leffler added reference to your answer from orignal post.